# Crystal Reports in ASP.NET/Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Is it possible to generate a CrystalReport without using the wizards of the DataSets and CrystalReports?

If so, which is the best way to tackle it?

So far, I've created an empty DataSet and an empty CrystalReport, and linked the CrystalReport to the latter DataSet using the wizard. Afterwords, I am creating a DataTable, putting this table into the DataSet and displaying it into a report. But an exception always generates telling me that no table was found. This is definetly not the case, since the same table is being viewed as a GridView at a previous stage.

Any help is highly appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the CrystalReport will generate some kind of schema - so when you first show it a empty set it won't find the table afterwards. There should be some kind of "refresh database" inside the wizard.

Normaly you wan't to create a typed-dataset (with the VS-Designer) and show this to the wizard. Then everything works rather fine.

OT:
But as a long time user of CR let me tell you: this tool is a pain in the A. - if there are more than one version of it on a system (and chances are pretty high for this) you will witness all kind of really bad behaviour.

Comment: does this mean that crystal report generation can be done only through the wizard? if not, which steps should i take? I cannot use the wizard due that the nature of the application has to be as secured as possible.

Comment: you want to define the layout yourself in code? I really don't know if this is possible - but there used to be code-constructs to validate and reinitialize the database(-scheme) through code. But it some years I had to do this and I think this part changed over the years - just play with intellisense and the document-class it should be there somewhere.

Comment: but I think you just want to create the report-document at runtime and export it or show it - right. Just feed the same kind of dataset/datatable you used in your layoutprocess to the Datasource(?) of the report and you should be fine - my appologies that I can't provide you with code/names but I don't have CR installed at home since it's not shipped with VS2010 anymore since SAP got it's hold on it.

Comment: @CKoenig - I think thats what he wants, exactly as you just said. He wants to bind a dataset/datatable to the report. Is this possible?

Comment: yes of course - on the document is a (...source - I *think* it's indeed a mehtod named SetDataSource) method where you cann put IEnumerables, DataSets, DataTables, etc. in (and you *will* have to cast a typed Datatable to (DataTable) to find the right overload) and that's it.

Comment: @CKoenig that what i am trying to do, but without any success... when creating a new crystal report and dataset, do they need to be empty (i.e. skip the wizard)? i am using the following code:   
           `CrystalReport1 rptDoc = new CrystalReport1();
            DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
         
            DataTable dt = DatabaseConnection.DatabaseHandler.GetCurrencyList();

            ds.Tables.Add(dt.Copy());
            
            rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds);
                        
            rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds);
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;`

Comment: the wizard is the design-tool right? You would make your live easier if you used typed-datasets (i.e. using the DataSet-designer in VS to create them too) - and no if you leave the CR-desing blank than your will not see a thing (obviously) ... I think I don't understand your question. BTW the code should run but normaly you don't need the DataSet - you can just use the Table without the DataSet-wrapper.

Comment: @Ckoenig Yes the wizard is the design tool. But what is the design you re mentioning in the Crystal Report? Can you please explain further on this regard on how to produce the required design? I used datasets since most tutorials use this wrapper, but in actual fact, youre right the SetDataSource overloads datatable as well.

Comment: with design I was thinking of putting fields and text and so on onto the CR-desinger (so you see something there). The dataset-designer is a seperate component in VS2010 - if you say "Add->New Item->/Data/DataSet" this designer will show up and you can define typed-datasets (to make your life easier - aka the rows will give you intellisense and so on). I never got problems this way (in crystalreport say the designer to look for this typed-data set and then use this datasets to fill your data with) BTW: what kind of data does the GetcurrencyList give?

Comment: getCurrentList returns a DataTable. I've tried adding a textbox to the CR (and previewed it to make sure that something appears) but the same exception is being generated... Just to make sure what you understood my question, I wish to bind a datatable dynamically during runtime to a crystal report (just like binding a datatable with a gridview during runtime for example).

Comment: have you connected the report to any kind of datasource (database, table, set) in the wizard? You have to - don't know if this is still the case but in earlier versions you had to save the datatables/set schema to a xml-schema file and import this in the report if you wanted to use it - as I said I allways do with the typed-datasets nowadays, so the CR loads the schema from there